# How do I display a GIF image when hovering over a point in another image in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousehover

I have a map with some locations marked with orange dots.

The map is in `.jpg` image format.

I placed it on my website, now I want to display another gif animated image, when someone **hovers** over a particular orange dot in the map image. Refer to the picture on the link below. The gif image to be displayed in every dot is different.

Help me solve this problem using `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5s1EBTl5WExcUNBTXR0aHFmYjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should use image maps.

Comment: Like Kyle Emmanuel said, could use image maps: here you go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slbAUX78iFI  a video on image maps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can i display a gif image in the same screen when mousehover these points, when the mouseleave the gif image should disappear

Comment: You should use html image map coordinates
for infor you can refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use an imagemap in combination with one or more DIVs
you show or hide and if needed change the position of your DIVs via JavaScript on mouseover

a little example

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
      #myOverlay{visibility:hidden; z-index:10; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;}
 </style>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function showDiv(imgUrl, x, y)
    {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myOverlay"); //get the div element
        myDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imgUrl + "' />" //overwrite the content
        myDiv.style.top = y; //set position top
        myDiv.style.left = x; //set position left
        myDiv.style.visibility = "visible"; //show the div
    }

    function hideDiv()
    {       
        document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide the div
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="yourFile.jpg"  usemap="#yourMapName"></img>
    <map name="yourMapName">
      <area shape="rect" coords="11,10,59,29" href = '#' onMouseOver="JavaScript:showDiv('yourOverlayImage1.gif',59,29);" onMouseOut="JavaScript:hideDiv()"alt="anyAlt1" title="anyTitle1">
     <area shape="rect" coords="110,100,159,129" href = '#' onMouseOver="JavaScript:showDiv('yourOverlayImage2.gif',159,129);" onMouseOut="JavaScript:hideDiv()"alt="anyAlt2" title="anyTitle2">
 </map>
 <div name="myOverlay" id="myOverlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

or 
you can draw your image as svg (http://www.w3.org/2000/svg) - i would not recommend that cause it's a lot of work

Answer (score -1):

You can use iframe to show a image:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="25" height="25" src="image1.gif" name="imgbox" id="imgbox">
```

And make a dot a link which will load new picture in iframe:

```
<a href="image2.gif" target="imgbox">dot</a>
```